# How should I create an SQLAlchemy model based on another class?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a regular class `Something` that basically just holds some fields. I need to make an SQLAlchemy model `SomethingModel` (in the ORM) that represents a `Something`-like object, with a couple extra fields (primary key, for example). What's the best way to do this?

So far, I've thought of having `SomethingModel` inherit from `Something`, but then I'm using multiple inheritance which I've heard is bad (`SomethingModel` would be inheriting from `Something` and SQLAlchemy's `Base`). I also thought that I could simply call `Something.__init__` from within `SomethingModel.__init__` - would that be better?

I am aware that I'll still need SQLAlchemy's column fields for the fields of `Something` that I want to save in `SomethingModel`. This also seems to make things a bit messier.

What's the "best" way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [classical mapping](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapper_config.html) for your class